# Changing value of variable in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have something like this

```
var position =  '-15.4165216,28.2794958,17';
```

Any simple solution?

OK from server i have that kind of position the problem is when i call google map api like this, how to make it like that

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: {
        lat: -15.4165216,
        lng: 28.2794958,17
    },
    styles: styles
});
```

Comment: Why jQuery?  Really all you need is a plain javascript object

Comment: I need string, simple string

Comment: It's unclear what exactly do you have and what exactly do you want. Both your examples are invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply

```
var newPosition = "lat: "+position.replace(",",",lng: ");
```

For your Seconde Asking here is it

```
var position =  '-15.4165216,28.2794958,17';
position = position.split(",");

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: position[2],
    center: {
        lat: position[0],
        lng: position[1]
    },
    styles: styles
});
```

Comment: This is best solution, can you see my updated question?

Comment: You want the String to be inserted on the Google map center object ?

Comment: No, id does not work, because you have two , in string. I need to split this one string in two var

Comment: Yes that's what i did , i did split the String to 3 variable but in one array ,

So in your case   position[0] = -15.4165216 | position[1] = 28.2794958| position[2] = 17

Answer (score 1):

No need of jQuery here, you can use Vanilla JS.

1. Your syntax is incorrect, use quotes
2. split the string using `,`
3. Create new string using the splitted array

```js
var position = '-15.4165216,28.2794958';

var arr = position.split(',');

var result = 'lat: ' + arr[0] + ', lng: ' + arr[1];

document.write(result);
```

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Check Updated answer

Comment: the problem is that sometimes i have like this
var positionAddress = -15.4165216,28.2794958,17;
You will see two commas, let you explain i am making google map from API, the problem is that from server i only get 

-15.4165216,28.2794958,17;

How to put that on lng and lat?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var position =  '-15.4165216,28.2794958,17';
var newPosition = position.split(',');
var stringOut = 'lat: ' + newPosition[0] + ',lng: ' + newPosition.slice(1).join(',');
```

but what is requiring such a weird format?

Comment: Yep and then i have a problem when i want to do like this on api


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: newPosition,
            styles: styles
        });

This will work 

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: {
                lat: -15.4165216,
                lng: 28.2794958
            },
            styles: styles
        });

Comment: I am not exactly following what's going on but that I gave you will get you the result you want. Diptox's as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can use javascript's split method check: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split

And you want and object

newposition= {lat:xxxx ,long:xxxx}